# Maven failsafe plugin - propagate system property set by maven plugin in pre-integration-test

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I've have a following problem and was not able to find any answer elsewhere:

I'm using https://github.com/joelittlejohn/embedmongo-maven-plugin for starting mongo db server in pre-integration-test phase and then run integration tests that interacts with mongo db on specified port. However, with original version of plugin I'm forced to hard code port in plugin configuration which can clash with some other processes running on same machine and effectively denies parallel executions of modules that uses the same port.

Therefore I've prepared a patch https://github.com/jumarko/embedmongo-maven-plugin/compare/jma-random-port that enables me to start mongo db on random port.
However, I'm not able to pass allocated port (allocated by plugin in pre-integration-test phase) to the integration itself running in forked JVM in integration-test phase (see https://github.com/jumarko/embedmongo-maven-plugin/blob/3462a909b546eab6afe1f87691ac49336ddab845/src/test/java/com/github/joelittlejohn/embedmongo/MongoIT.java).

I tried to set allocated port to system property (https://github.com/jumarko/embedmongo-maven-plugin/compare/jma-random-port#L1R201) but this property is not propagated to the forked JVM. As a workaround, I even tried to set this property in failsafe plugin configuration (https://github.com/jumarko/embedmongo-maven-plugin/compare/jma-random-port#L0R104) but it didn't have any effect (I guess that propery resolving happens before the embedmongo-plugin actually sets it).

Is there any way how to propagate system property set dynamically at runtime (by embedmongo-maven-plugin) to the forked JVM used for integration tests execution?
Are there any (possibly better) alternatives how to pass port the mongo db  is running on to the integration test itself?

Note: Integration test is able to access system property if failsafe plugin forkMode is set to never but this is not an option for me.

Comment: Have a look if the [argLine](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#argLine) option works for you. To propagate a system property to a test you normally have to run maven using `-DargLine="-DsomeProp=someValue"` instead of just `-DsomeProp=someValue`

Comment: My problem is that I don't know the property value  at configuration time (it is set by plugin at runtime), therefore I cannot set the proper value in pom.

Comment: Maybe it works if you configure the property in the surefire plugin pom section by using the [${env.<SystemPropertyName>}](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties) notation. As I understood the system property was set by a plugin and might be available now.

Comment: I've tried both approaches - via systemPropertyVariables and via argsLine - using ${env.embedmongo.port.embedmongo-maven-plugin} as well as ${embedmongo.port.embedmongo-maven-plugin} but none of them is working.

Comment: If you tested all possibilities that are described [here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html) (also 'Special VM properties') I am sorry - no idea left :-(

Comment: Finally, it works. I've examined [AbstractSurefireMojo](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-common/xref/org/apache/maven/plugin/surefire/AbstractSurefireMojo.html#755) and found that I can set port as a new user property via MavenSession#getUserProperties()

Comment: Fine. Would ne nice if you answer the question by yourself and mark it as aswered in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In your plugin you can set the project properties that will propagate to the failsafe plugin configuration by using the *AbstractMojo.project* field:

```
project.getProperties().put(propertyName,propertyValue);
```

I do this exact thing with a work project and it does what you want.

So if you have run

```
project.getProperties().put("the.port", 1234)
```

in the mojo then you will be able to use the property ${the.port} in the failsafe configuration.